# I have one XML file but two combo boxes I want to populate the second one depending on the first

Tags: xml, vb.net, combobox

I have got two comboboxes on my application. The first combobox can get all the required data (in this case it is the factory numbers) however depending on which factory is selected I want the next combo box (in this case line numbers) to automatically populate with the correct lines for that factory.
Here is my XML file - or a test data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profiles>
<Factories>
  <Factory>F1</Factory>

  <Factory>F2</Factory>

  <Factory>F3</Factory>

  <Factory>F4</Factory>

  <Factory>F5</Factory>
  <Factory>F6</Factory>
  <Factory>F7</Factory>
  <Factory>F8</Factory>
</Factories>

  <Lines>
    <F1>G1</F1>
    <F1>G2</F1>
    <F1>G3</F1>
  </Lines>
</Profiles>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub populateComboBoxes()
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("C:\TFS2010Source\ShopFloorApps\Main\Source\Components\000280LinePCBackup\000280LinePCBackup\Lines.XML")

    Dim factoryList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/Profiles/Factories/Factory")
    For Each Factory As XmlNode In factoryList
        factoryComboBox.Items.Add(Factory.InnerText)
    Next



End Sub

Private Sub factoryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles factoryComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("C:\TFS2010Source\ShopFloorApps\Main\Source\Components\000280LinePCBackup\000280LinePCBackup\Lines.XML")


    Dim lineList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/Profiles/Lines")

    For Each line As XmlNode In lineList


        If factoryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString = line.FirstChild.Name Then


            lineComboBox.Items.Add(line.FirstChild.InnerText)


        End If
        Next
End Sub
```

So What I want is when I select F1 the other combobox populates with the line G1,G2 and G3.

Thanks

Comment: I dont know how to populate the second combobox based on the one that has just been selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear the Items collection of `lineComboBox` and also change the `SelecteNodes` path.

```
lineComboBox.Items.Clear()
Dim lineList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/Profiles/Lines/" & factoryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString)
For Each line As XmlNode In lineList
    lineComboBox.Items.Add(line.FirstChild.InnerText)
Next
```

Comment: I had just done this and then checked again. Glad to see I managed to work it out in the end. Been stuck on it since yesterday, Thanks very much